# Does the target of #selector() depend on the context of `addObserver` (class vs object)?

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

The full test case below is supposed to demonstrate: a selector, even though it is specified identically in two places, is performed differently:  either it is performed on the class, or on the object. (I understand that a static method and an object method can share the same name, but there is only one below.) Whether the receiver is class or object seems to depend on where the “same” [selector](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0022-objc-selectors.md) is made known to `NSNotificationCenter`, either in class context or in method context:

1. a static method has the call to `addObserver`, or
2. an object method has the call `addObserver`

while the calls are otherwise identical.
If the identical call occurs in a static method, then when the notification is processed later, the system tries to invoke the selector on the class, not the object. The class does not have it. The code compiles fine with the new (in 2.2) syntax. Is this result to be expected?

```
import XCTest
import class Foundation.NSNotificationCenter  // for emphasis

class SelectorTests: XCTestCase {

    static let NotificationName = "OneTwoThreeNotification"

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self)
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func addObserverForTestNormal() { // <- HERE
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(SelectorTests.myMethod(_:)),  // <- HERE
            name: SelectorTests.NotificationName,
            object: nil)
    }

    func testNormal() {
        self.addObserverForTestNormal()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            SelectorTests.NotificationName,
            object: self)
    }

    static func addObserverForTestStatic() { // <- HERE
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(SelectorTests.myMethod(_:)),  // <- HERE
            name: SelectorTests.NotificationName,
            object: nil)

    }

    func testStatic() {
        SelectorTests.addObserverForTestStatic()
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(
            SelectorTests.NotificationName,
            object: self)
    }

    func myMethod(x : Int) {
        XCTAssert(true)
    }

}
```

One test succeeds, the other fails. The gist of the stack trace and message is

> "+[KuckuckTests.SelectorTests myMethod:]: unrecognized selector sent to class

Is this schism, i.e. class or object “inferred” from `addObserver`-context, so obvious to old Objective-C hands that it isn't worth mentioning with `#selector`? In this case, could you point out some documentation?

**Edit**:  just noticed that `self` in the static function's invocation
of `addObserver` is perhaps referring to the class, not to some object. That makes the effect somewhat plausible, and suggests that programmers  should know what overloaded names stand for…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing about a `#selector` expression has any connection to the use site of that selector. A selector names a message, and says nothing about the receiver of that message. You can use a `#selector` expression to create a `Selector` value for a method on one object, then pass that `Selector` value to an API (like `NSNotificationCenter.addObserver` or `UIControl.sendAction` or `NSTimer.init`) that'll result in sending a message with that selector to some completely different object.

This loose binding is an intentional part of the dynamic nature of the Objective-C runtime Cocoa uses for passing these messages (regardless of whether the functions referenced by your selectors are build in ObjC or Swift). The `#selector` expression, and the Swift function-reference syntax it depends on, give you a way to "sorta" strongly type your use of selectors, but only on one end — they let you verify that the `Selector` value you're constructing refers to a specific method. (But once you have a `Selector` value, how it gets used is out of Swift's control.)

Your error message (emphasis added):

> unrecognized selector sent to **class**

...indicates that the failure is because the message is being sent to the `SelectorTests` class object (aka the metaclass object). That is, by scheduling a notification to be sent to `self` in a `static` method, you're asking for a call to `class func myMethod`, not to `func myMethod`.

The `self` keyword always refers to the instance responsible for the code that's executing: inside an instance method, `self` refers to the current instance. Inside a class method, `self` refers to the (only instance of) the class object.